# Curve sketching without a computer program

Tags: calculus

How to sketch the curve x^6 + y^6 = (x^4)*y without using a computer program ? Could someone give me the step by step ?

Comment: What do you mean sketch?  In general you would want to find all the points where y' or y'' is 0.  Those are going to be the interesting points and you can connect those.  Although you may have to find x' and x'' depending on the function.

Answer (score 2):

$\dfrac{y^6}{x^4} = y - x^2$, so there are no solutions whenever $y - x^2 < 0$. Whenever $y - x^2 = 0$, we find (by substitution) that the only solution is the origin. Notice that the curve is symmetric with respect to the y-axis, that is $(-x,y)$ is a solution if $(x,y)$ is a solution. Therefore, it is only necessary to graph the curve in the region bounded by the parabola $y = x^2$ and the y-axis. You may also want to ask if the curve is bounded in its y-component. In fact, if $y = 1$, then $x^6 - x^4 - 1 = 0$. The polynomial $f(x) = x^6 - x^4$ is pretty simple to graph with the three roots $(-1,0), (0,0),$ and $(1,0)$. By translating the graph of $x^6 - x^4$ down by one unit, to obtain the graph of $x^6 - x^4 - 1$, we see that there are two roots: one whose x-component is less than -1 and the other whose x-component is greater than 1, yet these points do not belong in the region that we described. This may be generalized for any $y \geq 1$, so the curve must be bounded above by $y = 1$.

In polar coordinate form, recall $x = r\cos(\theta)$ and $y = r\sin(\theta)$.

$x^6 + y^6 = r^6\cos^6(\theta) + r^6\sin^6(\theta) = r^6[\cos^2(\theta) + \sin^2(\theta)][\cos^4(\theta) - \cos^2(\theta)\sin^2(\theta)+\sin^4(\theta)] = r^6[\cos^4(\theta) - \cos^2(\theta)\sin^2(\theta)+\sin^4(\theta)]$

The equation $x^6 + y^6 = x^4y$ becomes

$r^6[\cos^4(\theta) - \cos^2(\theta)\sin^2(\theta)+\sin^4(\theta)] = r^5\cos^4(\theta)\sin(\theta).$ We may divide appropriately since we've already discussed the points at which division would not be well-defined.

$r = \dfrac{\sin(\theta)}{1 - \tan^2(\theta) + \tan^4(\theta)}$

You may plot a few points of the form $(r,\theta)$ by way of a trigonometric table: $\big(\frac{9}{14}, \frac{\pi}{6}\big), \big(\frac{1}{\sqrt{2}},\frac{\pi}{4}\big), \big(\frac{\sqrt{3}}{14}, \frac{\pi}{3}\big)$.

Comment: +1 This is really awkward to plot well without computer help. 

[![enter image description here][1]][1]

  [1]: http://i.stack.imgur.com/t5N3c.jpg

Answer (score 1):

If $x=0$ or $y=0$ the given equation enforces $x=y=0$. Therefore assume $xy\ne0$. Then the equation is equivalent with
$${x^2\over y}+{y^5\over x^4}=1\ .$$
Put
$${x^2\over y}=:u,\quad{y^5\over x^4}=:v\ .$$
Then on the one hand $u+v=1$, and on the other hand
$$x^6=u^5 v,\quad y^3=u^2 v\ .$$
This leads to the following "formal" parametric representation of the solution set:
$$u\mapsto(x,y):=\left(\root 6\of{u^5(1-u)},\> \root3\of{u^2(1-u)}\>\right)\qquad(-\infty<u<\infty)\ ,\tag{1}$$ 
whereby you will obtain $\geq0$ admissible values, depending on the choice of $u$ and the sign of the sixth root. At any rate, the representation $(1)$ allows to produce  arbitrarily many points of the solution set with the help of a pocket calculator.